# Android: Access to "/data/user/" in Android Handy without root?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-storage

I am developing an app for Android Handys. The data directory for this app is in 
"/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files" 
To see what is happening there while programming, I would like to access to this folder. Read rights would be enough.
I didn't find any file explorer which can access to this folder.
With vx file manager I came to /data, but not in /data/user.

Do anyone know a solution without root?

PS: my Samsung test handy is quite old (Android 7.0)